# DevExpress GridControl cells' inner text selectable but not editable

Tags: devexpress, edit, gridcontrol

GridControl is working like~ Excel natively:

1. Clicking **once** on the cell **selects it**. Copy copies the cell value and the header.
2. Clicking **twice** on the cell **selects the inner text**. Copy copies only the inner text.

I am working on preventing the cell edition hooking the `ShowingEditor` event, setting the edition to `e.Cancel`.

However this prevents the behaviour 2. above. I'd like to still **be able to select the inner text for copy**, just that I'd like it to be **not editable**.

Would you know how to do this? Fyi, this behavior can be achieved at a column level by setting the `ReadOnly` to true:

```
<dxg:GridControl.Columns>
    <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="field" ReadOnly="True"/>
```

---

**EDIT**

My grid is setup like this:

```
<dxg:GridControl>
    <dxg:GridControl.Resources>
    </dxg:GridControl.Resources>
    <dxg:GridControl.View>
        <dxg:GridControl.TableView>
        </dxg:GridControl.TableView>
    </dxg:GridControl.View>
    <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
    </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
</dxg:GridControl>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
GridView.OptionsBehavior.CopyToClipboardWithColumnHeaders = False
```

Also you could try this approach suggested by DevExpress

[Copy single cell content to clipboard from XtraGrid when user presses Ctrl+C](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q305020)

Comment: Hi. Thank you but seems you're using a GridView instead of a GridControl. Not sure what's the difference exactly but can't make it working. Note: I've posted another related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921145/whats-the-difference-between-gridcontrol-and-gridview-in-devexpress

Comment: Actually, from the doc (WPF), the function is obsolete: 

"Obsolete. Gets or sets whether column captions are copied to the clipboard when copying row values. (Inherited from DataViewBase)"

https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridTableViewClassPropTopic