# DevExpress GridControl selectable cell's text but not editable

Tags: wpf, xaml, devexpress, cells, gridcontrol

I am looking to be able to **set a cell editability** so that it is possible to *select the inner text of a cell in a GridControl without being able to modify it*.

Note: this behavior can be achieved at a column level by setting the ReadOnly to true, however want it at **cell level**

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [DevExpress GridControl cells' inner text selectable but not editable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26172343/devexpress-gridcontrol-cells-inner-text-selectable-but-not-editable)

Comment: @DmitryG - It's not a duplication.  for this situation, the solution would be to create a named style with a targettype of the cell editor type, include a setter for property "IsEnabled" and bind that to a view model or back end property returning a boolean value.

Answer (score 2):

Try assigning a RespositoryItemTextEdit control that cell within the GridView's [CustomRowCellEdit event](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomRowCellEdittopic). Set the ReadOnly property of this RepositoryItemTextEdit to True and assign it to the cell based on your conditions.

```
private void gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column == gridView1.Columns["EmployeeName"] && e.RowHandle == 2)
    {
        //Don't allow users to edit Employee Name in the third row cell
        RepositoryItemTextEdit readOnlyTextEdit = new RepositoryItemTextEdit();
        readOnlyTextEdit.ReadOnly = true;

        e.RepositoryItem = readOnlyTextEdit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But are you talking about WinForm or WPF? I'm using a GridControl > TableView and can't find where to hook that event