# What's the difference between GridControl and GridView in DevExpress?

Tags: c#, grid, devexpress

What's the difference between GridControl and GridView in DevExpress?
It seems GridControl is WinForm and GridView is WPF, however I am using gxg:GridContol in my XAML...
Is there also any relationship between these?
Found [this](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/clsDevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseViewtopic) for GridView, none for GridControl.

Reason is that each time I'm looking for help tp solve my GridControl issues ([DevExpress GridControl cells' inner text selectable but not editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26172343/devexpress-gridcontrol-cells-inner-text-selectable-but-not-editable/26678324#26678324)), I am being answered with a GridView instead of GridControl.

FYI, my grid is setup like this:

```
<dxg:GridControl>
    <dxg:GridControl.Resources>
    </dxg:GridControl.Resources>
    <dxg:GridControl.View>
        <dxg:GridControl.TableView>
        </dxg:GridControl.TableView>
    </dxg:GridControl.View>
    <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
    </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
</dxg:GridControl>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are [`GridControl`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument3461) class for `WinForms`<sup>0</sup> and [`GridControl`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#wpf/clsDevExpressXpfGridGridControltopic) class for `WPF`<sup>1</sup>. `GridView` is used by `WinForms`'s `GridControl` to show data in table-like view. There are no `GridView` in `WPF`.

Some relationship between classes:

0. GridControl for WinForms is using this [views](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument3463):

- [GridView](https://documentation.devexpress.com/windowsforms/clsDevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridViewtopic.aspx)
- [BandedGridView](https://documentation.devexpress.com/windowsforms/clsDevExpressXtraGridViewsBandedGridBandedGridViewtopic.aspx)
- [AdvBandedGridView](https://documentation.devexpress.com/windowsforms/clsDevExpressXtraGridViewsBandedGridAdvBandedGridViewtopic.aspx)
- [LayoutView](https://documentation.devexpress.com/windowsforms/clsDevExpressXtraGridViewsLayoutLayoutViewtopic.aspx)
- [CardView](https://documentation.devexpress.com/windowsforms/clsDevExpressXtraGridViewsCardCardViewtopic.aspx)
- [WinExplorerView](https://documentation.devexpress.com/windowsforms/clsDevExpressXtraGridViewsWinExplorerWinExplorerViewtopic.aspx)

1. GridControl for WPF is using this [views](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6300):

- [TableView](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/clsDevExpressXpfGridTableViewtopic.aspx)
- [CardView](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/clsDevExpressXpfGridCardViewtopic.aspx)
- [TreeListView](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/clsDevExpressXpfGridTreeListViewtopic.aspx)

<sup><sup>0</sup> XtraGrid Suite

<sup>1</sup> DXGrid Suite</sup>